# Extracting Meta Tags from HTML string using only Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, zapier

I have received the HTML of webpage as a string and I am trying to extract values from within HTML tags contained in the string, more specifically meta tags.  I've found ways to do this through jQuery, however the platform I am using does not allow JQuery plus the html I am extracting is technically a string so there is no need for html.  I am hoping to extract each meta tag and save them into an array to be used later.  Any regex solutions?

```
var rawHTML=input.rawHTML;
var HTMLlength=rawHTML.length;
var metas=rawHTML.split(">");
var testString="This is a <body>Test String for Regex</body>";
for(var i=0;i<metas.length;i++)
  {
   metas[i]=metas[i]+">";
  }
var twitterResults;
for(var i=0;i<metas.length;i++)
  {
   metas[i]=strip_html_tags(metas[i]);
   //twitterResults = testString.match(<TAG\b[^>]*>(.*?)<);
  }
```

Most importantly I am trying to do a regex expression to extract these tags as

```
/<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>
```

but it seems I can't break out of the regex and won't accept a semi-colon as a semi-colon and just give an error

Comment: Please share string sample , and your try ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression for this, but I would actually load the string into a DOM documentFragment and then parse the fragment for `meta` tags by looking for nodes of type `1` with a `nodeName === META`.